# Disk utility killed my external drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have a problem with disk utility. I have a external USB3 drive, formatted HFS+. It should hold roughly 500GB out of 1TB of Data. Now Finder told me, that the data was there but no files were visible (out of the blue, of course).

When I ran First Aid in disk utility, it immediately returned a "operation complete" (or the likes - my OS is running on German). Unfortunately my volume is now toast, displays as untitled, is unmountable and is displayet to be full to the last bit with "other".

Did I mention, I'm a bit desperate?

Comment: Do try `diskutil verifyDisk /Volumes/<your-disk-name>` and see if that brings up any additional errors. Also, do please add what you *did* with the disk that landed you in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Running Diskutil in command line mode is pretty much the same as running it in the GUI and that is the right way to go: select the disk and click on repair. Or do it the way "perhapsmaybeharry" indicated. Either should work.

If that fails you may need to try a dedicated disk repair program (I use Diskwarrior but there are others that work well too).

Likely a bad sector cropped up at the wrong place at the wrong time that the drive firmware could not fix. It is unlikely that Disk Utility did anything. And another disk repair utility *may* be able to fix this.

If it can't you may have to send it off to a data recovery company, but that is expensive and DiskWarrior (or others) is likely to fix it.